# Is it possible to include files in macOS bundle without using Xcode?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

So, I've been trying to include shaders inside macOS bundle for a while, and only way I have found, was adding them through Xcode.
It would be nice if it would be possible to do something like that but only with CMake:
[image: Bundle example]

Comment: A "bundle" is just a folder with a specific structure and the extension ".app".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, It looks like I found a solution:

```
set(VS_SHADER_NAME "cgui_tri_vertex.vs")
set(VS_SHADER_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/${VS_SHADER_NAME})
file(COPY ${VS_SHADER_PATH} DESTINATION "${PROJECT_NAME}.app/Contents/Resources")
```

Comment: Looks good to me (and I think you're copying them to the right place).  Note that any `.dylibs` need to be copied to `Contents/Frameworks` (and signed).